# AWS Codepipeline - run integration tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

first of all, sorry, if my question is to broad..., but I'm looking for solution approaches, instead of asking exact questions.

Now, we are migrating our (c++) development into AWS (AWS CodeCommit, CodePipeline, etc).
The development workflow is very common: edit the code, build (the build executes UNIT Tests), and run integration test.

The integration test requires database, the running production process (single process application) and the test process.

Now, I have an AWS CodePipeline that is (in AWS CodePipeline stage order)

1. Check out the source if changed (AWS CodeCommit)
2. Build it and output the binaries (AWS CodeBuild)
3. Create 2 docker images (for production process and for integration test process) and upload them to Amazon ECR (AWS CodeBuild)

**The problem**

is that I couldn't found any suitable steps that the pipeline can trigger and and which step will start these containers and runs the integration tests (and of course in case of failure, raise an error on the pipeline too)

**My initial**

idea was to create an ECS Cluster with FARGATE task definition and the pipeline "executes" this task

So please help me how to achieve this goal (by completing my initial thought or proposing a new one)...

The important is that I want to be sure that if I submit a commit to the branch it will be **built, unit tested and integration tested**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeBuild can run any script, not just build scripts. You should add another step to your pipeline that runs another CodeBuild step that runs your integration tests.

Comment: Do you mean that I should declare an AWS Fargate task it will be called / triggered / etc from AWS Codebuild script?

If so, does it wait for task to be complete?

Sorry, but AWS ECS if fairly new for me, and on the AWS Console, I couldn't see any control (button) just to trigger the task (e.g. for testing purpose). It is very confusing for me

Comment: Are you trying to run these tests against a deployed application (in which case they are really end-to-end tests, not integration tests) or are you asking more about how to run a temporary database/etc.. as part of an integration test suite? If the later, then I suggest looking into Testcontainers https://www.testcontainers.org/ which could be used to run all your dependencies inside a CodeBuild task.

Comment: Using this terminology, they are end-to-end tests. Now, my build pipeline deploys 2 containers to Amazon ECR, one for running the test executable, the other to run the product binary. My assumption was that it is possible, to declare an ECS Fargate task, that refer these images and this task can be triggered on-demand as a next build step in my pipeline. The problem is that I don't understand how to trigger such a task (even if it is possible) the another one is, is this the correct way to perform end-to-end testing in AWS Codepipeline

Comment: You appear to be asking how to deploy an ECS application via CodePipeline, but your question was initially about how to run tests against that application after it was deployed. You need to get your application deployment process nailed down first, before attempting to test a deployed application.

Comment: Your question about "is this the correct way" depends entirely on what you want to accomplish. You could possibly run ALL your containers inside a CodeBuild task, with dependencies running in Testcontainers, and test the entire thing inside that single Codebuild task without using ECS Fargate at all. But you seem to be focusing on deploying to Fargate and then running tests against Fargate. If that's what you want to do, then look into adding an AWS CodeDeploy step in your CodePipeline to deploy your application to ECS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store your code base to aws code commit and from there just trigger the lambda/ step function for unit testing, integration testing, etc.

In lemon words all you can do is create dummy container that will run your test cases and you can use the deploy stage to do the deployment over your container or skip the last step.